# SQL how to use a String concatenation together with a WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, csv

I have a problem where i need to make a very customized CSV file with Payment Data for billing printing.

The CSV must have a header with multiple custom useful information and the Payment Data should come under it. I managed to make both but i cant use UNION ALL and ORDER BY together and if i dont, the Payment Data comes out as a complete mess.

Here is how the code looks like

```
WITH LOTE_GRAFICA AS
(SELECT MAX(FIN.NUMCONTRATO) AS CONTRATO, MAX(FIN.DTVENC) AS VENCIMENTO,
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.CPF), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.NOMEPARC), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(ENDER.TIPO), '')) + ' ' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.NOMEEND), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.NUMEND), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(PAR.COMPLEMENTO), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.NOMEBAI), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.NOMECID), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.UF), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(COALESCE(MAX(CON.CEP), '')) + '|' + 
        TRIM(CAST(REPLACE(MAX(FIN.VLRDESDOB), '.', '')AS varchar(10))) + '|' + 
        TRIM(CONVERT(varchar, FIN.DTVENC, 3)) + '|' + 
        TRIM(MAX(FIN.NOSSONUM)) + '|' + 
        TRIM(CAST(MAX(FIN.NUFIN) AS varchar(20))) + '|' + 
        TRIM(MAX(FIN.LINHADIGITAVEL)) + '|' + 
        TRIM(MAX(FIN.CODIGOBARRA)) + '|' + 
        TRIM(CAST(MAX(FIN.NUMCONTRATO) AS varchar(30))) + '|' + 
        TRIM(MAX(CON.PLANO)) + '|' + 
        TRIM(MAX(FIN.DESDOBRAMENTO)) AS CONTEUDO
FROM SANKHYA.AD_VGFREAJCON REAJ
INNER JOIN SANKHYA.TGFFIN FIN ON (FIN.NUMCONTRATO = REAJ.NUMCONTRATO)
INNER JOIN SANKHYA.TGFPAR PAR ON (FIN.CODPARC = PAR.CODPARC)
INNER JOIN SANKHYA.PREVENIR_APP_CONTRATO CON ON (PAR.CODPARC = CON.CODPARC)
INNER JOIN SANKHYA.TSIEND  ENDER ON (PAR.CODEND = ENDER.CODEND)
INNER JOIN SANKHYA.TCSCON STAT ON (STAT.NUMCONTRATO = CON.CONTRATO)
WHERE
REAJ.LOTEREAJ = 188
AND REAJ.FATURADO = 'S'
AND FIN.CODBCO = 237
AND FIN.DTVENC > GETDATE()+20
AND FIN.DTVENC < GETDATE()+400
AND FIN.NOSSONUM IS NOT NULL
AND FIN.VLRDESDOB > 1
AND FIN.DHBAIXA IS NULL
AND FIN.RECDESP = 1
AND FIN.NURENEG IS NULL
AND FIN.AD_ADESAO IS NULL
AND PAR.CGC_CPF IS NOT NULL
AND STAT.AD_STATUS = 'ATIVO'
GROUP BY CON.CONTRATO, FIN.DTVENC)


SELECT '04.333.253/0001-38' + '|' + 'PREVENIRASSISTENCIAL LTDA' + '|' + 'Av. Brasilia 1165, Loja 01 - Duquesa I - Sao Benedito - Santa Luzia - MG' + '|' + '237-2' + '|' + '3435' + '|' + '63184' + '|' + '1' + '|' + TRIM(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 3)) + '|' + TRIM(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 3)) + '|' + 'N' + '|' + 'DS' + '|' + '2' + '|' + 'R$' + '|' + '33170-000' AS ' '

UNION ALL

SELECT CONTEUDO FROM LOTE_GRAFICA 
ORDER BY CONTRATO, VENCIMENTO
```

Anyone know how i can make this work ? Maybe its possible to run 2 separate queries and join them together after in the same file, but i dont know how to do it. Making it manually works, but i need to deliver a solution thats makes is without human intervention.

I expect to have a CSV file with payment data ordered by contract number and due date with a custom header on top.

Thank you all for your time, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can't you do order by case when contrato = '04.333.253/0001-38' then 0 else 1 end, contrato, vencimento

Comment: Make the client code prepend the header.

Comment: This is really not a job for SQL Server. You should just use a proper tool like Powershell `Invoke-DbaQuery ...... | Out-CSV .....`

Comment: Tip - you could tidy this significantly by using `concat_ws`